Automotive Emulator onMapReady not called
I have a working app that displays a map and the route driven.
I have now added an Automotive module to it and I can start running the new module on an Automotive emulator.
Things work fine for everything, except that the onMapReady Callback is never called in this case.
When I let the module run on a normal phone emulator, the callback is called.
This would point to a missing configuration in the Automotive emulator, but I cant find anything like that.
Anyone having a idea what the reason could be?

Does the emulator have Internet access? Does Logcat show anything of note?

yes, it has Internet access and I can run all functions where Internet is needed. Logcat shows nothing abnormal. I see the mapfragment.getMapAsync(this); stlll being called and not producing any error message

Which Automotive emulator you used?

Automotive (1080p landscape). What is strange is that when I try to use the (1024p landscape) with the Google Play icon next to it, there is no recommended system image. Under 'Other images' I get only API Level 29 or 28 to download, which is rather useless as my minsdk is 30.

https://developer.android.com/training/cars/testing/emulator#bundled-profiles has details on which hardware profiles work with which images (https://developer.android.com/training/cars/testing/emulator#generic-images)

Just deleted the Virtual devices and recreated them, and all of a sudden it works without any change in code.
